# MySQL Select a user's rank in a dynamically generated leaderboard

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of user predictions which I use to generate a leaderboard of top users and their ranks.

The table (`predictions`) looks like this:

```
  id  |  userid  |  fixtureid   |  correct
  1   |    1     |      1       |     1
  2   |    2     |      5       |     0
  3   |    2     |      6       |     1
  4   |    2     |      7       |     1
  5   |    3     |      6       |     0
```

Currently I use this query to generate the leaderboard and then loop through results:

```
SELECT userid, (correct * 3) AS score 
FROM predictions 
GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

This would then display a leaderboard similar to this, the rank is calculated in php using `$i++;` after each row:

```
User Id  |  Score  |
    2    |    6    | #Rank is 1
    1    |    3    | #Rank is 2
    3    |    0    | #Rank is 3
```

**What I'm trying achieve**

I want to be able to find out a user's rank in the leaderboard without building the whole table and just using their `userid`.

How can I do this bearing in mind that the users could increase to a large number in the future?

**Psuedo code** of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT rank 
FROM predictions
WHERE userid = 3
```

Which would return:

```
User Id  |  Score  |
    3    |    0    | #Rank is 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how you generated the column "Position", but anyways, 
have you explored the possibility of using a **View**?

You only need to run this command ONCE:

```
CREATE VIEW `leaderboard` AS
SELECT 
    userId, 
    (correct * 3) AS score 
FROM predictions 
GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Then you would treat the created view as a normal table in your application.

Here is an example on how you would use it:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leaderboard WHERE score >= L.score) AS position,
    L.userid,
    L.score
FROM leaderboard L
WHERE L.userid = 3
```

Comment: The `rank`/`position` is generated dynamically in php using `$i++` per record, it doesn't actually exist which makes it harder.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use aggregate `sum` function to get total score by user id.

Try this:

```
select
  Rank, userid, score 
from (
    SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 as Rank, userid, sum(correct * 3) AS score 
    FROM predictions
         , (select @rn:=0) row_nums 
    GROUP BY userid 
    ORDER BY score DESC
) user_ranks
where userid=3;
```

**Demo** @ [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15707/1)